# JQuery Check to See if Div is Shown

Tags: jquery, css, html

This is what I am ultimately trying to achieve:

```
//When the user clicks the liveshow button this happens
$(".liveshow-button").live('click', function() {
    if ($(".liveshowDiv2").css('display') == 'none') {
        $(".liveshowDiv2").fadeOut(ifadeOutSpeed, function() {
            $('#wrapper-div').animate({ 
                height: $('.liveshowDiv1').height() + "px" 
            }, 
            iresizeSpeed, function() {
                $('.liveshowDiv1').fadeIn(ifadeInSpeed, function());
            });
        });
    }
    else {
        alert('This never gets displayed');
        $(".liveshowDiv1").slideUp('fast');
    }
});
```

Basically I want to toggle between liveShowDiv1 being displayed and hidden when you click this button.  But since other things on the page can make liveShowDiv1 hidden, I can't just make a toggle function to do this.  I have to check somehow to see if liveShowDiv1 is being displayed or not.

**When it not displayed: display = none**

**When it is showing display is not in the style tag at all**

**How can I tell in JQuery when this div is displayed?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-you-test-if-something-is-hidden-in-jquery

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`if ( $(this).is(':visible') )` should work for this relatively simple show/hide.

Comment: I swear I knew that at some point in time.  Surprised I coudldn't figure it out on google.

Answer (score 26):

Sometime need to check that div is block or none. We can do this very easily . This is simple code . here `id = "test"` -> for testing purpose if you use `class = "test"` then need to update code
For checking Block or visible then use this for your select `test` is `id`

```
1. if ($('#test').is(':visible')) {}

2. if ($('#test').css('display') == 'block'){}

3. if ($('#test').not(':hidden')){}
```

if your selector is `class` then

```
1. if ($('.test').is(':visible')) {}
```

or

```
1. if ($(your_element).is(':visible')) {}
```

same other

For checking none or hide then use this code if your `selector` is `id`

```
1. if ($('#test').not(':visible')){}

2. if (!$('#test').is(':visible')){}

3. if ($('#test').css('display') == 'none'){}

4. if ($('#test').is(':hidden')){}
```

if your selector is class then use this

```
1. if ($('.test').not(':visible')){}
```

or

```
1. if ($(your_element).not(':visible')){}
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
$(your_element).is(":visible")
```

Example;

```
if ($('#element_id').is(":visible") ) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$(element).is(":visible")` to check if the element is visible