# How to know the status of the div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show, status

i am developin one application using `jquery`. i want to know the status of the `div` wheather the `div` is show state or hide state 
something like this:

```
if($("#test").show()==true) 
{
//some operration
}
else
{
//some operration
}
```

`alert($("#test").show()==true);` always shows `false`.

please help me...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use is() and the :visible selector.

```
if( $('#test').is(':visible') ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
$(element).is(":visible")
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-you-test-if-something-is-hidden-in-jquery)
**Note** : [hidden fails on elements that have width but no height.](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4374)

Answer (score 1):

`is(':visible')` is, of course, correct.

In pretty much all my jQuery applications, I introduce a simple plugin `isVisible`.

```
$.fn.isVisible = function() {
    return $.expr.filters.visible(this[0]);
};
```

This is about 50 times faster than the above function ([jsPerf example](http://jsperf.com/jquery-visibility-test)) for exactly the same functionality.

```
if ($('#yourElement').isVisible()) {
```