# jQuery - testing slideToggle state with an animation?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've used some of the [information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-you-test-if-something-is-hidden-in-jquery) to create a toggle state check, which worked fine with a regular instant toggle, but how do I apply it to a slideToggle with slow animation? Here's my code:

```
$('#elemToggle').click(function() {
    $("#elem").slideToggle('slow');
    if($("#elem").is(":visible")) {
        $('#elemToggle').addClass('down');
        $('#elemToggle').removeClass('up');
    } else {
        $('#elemToggle').addClass('up');
        $('#elemToggle').removeClass('down');
    }
    return false;
});
```

The above doesn't work since when you hit the button, technically the elem is still visible and just being collapsed. Any ideas for a workaround please?! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do your check on the complete callback of `slideToggle()`

```
$('#elemToggle').click(function() {
    $("#elem").slideToggle('slow', function() {
      if($("#elem").is(":visible")) {
        $('#elemToggle').addClass('down');
        $('#elemToggle').removeClass('up');
      } else {
        $('#elemToggle').addClass('up');
        $('#elemToggle').removeClass('down');
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Here the [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Comment: this is great, thanks! think i'll go with this, I like the way it keeps track of the state too so if you spam the toggle button it'll always end on the right class :)

Answer (score 1):

You could just move the test before the `toggle` and invert it.  If the element is visible before the `toggle` then you know it is going to be hidden and the same for the opposite.

Although from the looks of it, I would probably not use toggle for this and instead use `show` and `hide` and keep track of the state myself.

Comment: this is a great idea, thank you - i like the idea of keeping track of the state via show/hide too