# In jQuery UI tabs, how do I get the tab element by its tab index?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have the following JavaScript function to select a tab by its index:

```
function changeTab(tabIndex) {
    $("#panel").tabs("select", tabIndex);
}
```

But I have to check if that tab exists **and** if it's visible, or else it would try to select a tab that shouldn't be available.

For the existence it's fine, I just have to use `$("#panel").tabs("length");`, but to [check if it is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-you-test-if-something-is-hidden-in-jquery) I would need the element itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there isn't a built-in method for that, but I was able to accomplish it by navigating to the tab:

```
function changeTab(tabIndex) {
    var panel = $("#panel");
    var queryIndex = tabIndex + 1; // 1 based
    var desiredTab = panel.find("> ul li:nth-child( " + queryIndex + ")");

    if (desiredTab && desiredTab.is(":visible")) {
        panel.tabs("select", tabIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested but you should be able to get the index of the selected tab by

```
var activeIndex = $("#panel").tabs( "option" , 'selected')
```

And then you should be able to just very that activeIndex equals tabIndex

Comment: Doesn't help because that will happen after the tab has been selected, which is what I want to avoid. I found a way by navigating to the tab, but I won't be able to answer my own question in the next 5 hours because of my low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

First get the Active index

```
var activeIndex = $("#panel").tabs('option', 'active');
```

Then using the css class get the tab content panel

```
// this will return the html element
var element=   $("#panel").find( ".ui-tabs-panel" )[activeIndex];
```

now wrapped it in jQuery object to further use it

```
 var tabContent$ = $(element);
```

here i want to add two info the class `.ui-tabs-nav` is for Navigation associated with  and `.ui-tabs-panel` is associated with tab content panel. in this link demo in jquery ui website you will see this class is used - http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation