# Check div is hidden using jQuery

Tags: jquery, hidden, visible

This is my div

```
<div id="car2" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Then I have a Show button that will show the div when you click:

```
$("show").click(function() {
    $("$car2").show();
});
```

So right now I want to check if the div `#car2` is still hidden before form submission:

```
if($('#car2').is(':hidden')) {
    alert('car 2 is hidden');
}
```

Now here is the problem. Although the div `#car2` already show, I still got alert message which means that jQuery assumes the div `#car2` is still hidden.

My jQuery version is 1.7.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

As jasper said, my code is correct and can be run via this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YjP4K/2/).

What I suspect there is some conflict with [jQuery form to wizard plugin](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx) that I am using with my form. Anyone have any idea to solve this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YjP4K/2/ Your code does work when simplified so maybe you have an error somewhere else?

Comment: See also [Checking if an element is hidden \[by jquery\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/checking-if-an-element-is-hidden)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can check the CSS `display` property:

```
if ($('#car').css('display') == 'none') {
    alert('Car 2 is hidden');
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YjP4K/

Comment: although other answer is correct, but somehow i can only use this method in my form so i will choose this as an answer. thanks.

Comment: `$('#car').is(:hidden)` should work. This also is a cleaner solution than the current one. Check more at https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Comment: @akshay yeah that makes more semantic sense. I think there are edge cases where doing your own check makes sense because there are conditions around the element(s) that screw with the `:hidden` and `:visible` selectors.

Comment: @akshay you forgot the quotes on :hidden. It should be $('#car').is(':hidden')

Answer (score 31):

Try:

```
if(!$('#car2').is(':visible'))
{  
    alert('car 2 is hidden');       
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
if($('#car2').is(':hidden'))
{  
    alert('car 2 is hidden');       
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try checking for the :visible property instead.

```
if($('#car2').not(':visible'))
{
    alert('car 2 is hidden');       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you notice your typo, `$car2` instead of `#car2` ?

Anyway, `:hidden` seems to be working as expected, try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/smendola/hDkz8/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```
if (!$("#car-2").is(':visible'))
{
      alert('car 2 is hidden');
}
```