# jquery - show elements after closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, navigation

Currently I have a full screen menu feature going on. When I click the menu button, I want my `.title` div to disappear. Which is working. But when I close my menu, the `.title` div remains gone. I want the div to reappear when I exit my full screen menu.

**JavaScript**

```
$(".navvy").click(function(){
    $(".title").hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
<div class="navvy">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
  <label for="toggle" id="toggle-btn"></label>
  <div class="nav-icon"></div>
  <nav data-state="close">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header></div>

<div class="title">
<center><img src=http://i60.tinypic.com/wj73mg.png></center>
TITLE
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484251/check-div-is-hidden-using-jquery This will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `.mouseout()` on the `div.navvy` element and pass `.mouseout(f)` an anonymous function that would `.show()` the `div.title`

https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Example for your browser js console to be used on https://stackoverflow.com

```
$("#question-header").click( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mainbar").hide();
} )
.mouseout( function () { $("#mainbar").show(); } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```js
$(".navvy").click(function() {
  $(".title").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="navvy">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
    <label for="toggle" id="toggle-btn"></label>
    <div class="nav-icon"></div>
    <nav data-state="close">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Team</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</div>


<div class="title">
  <center>
    <img src=http://i60.tinypic.com/wj73mg.png>
  </center>
  TITLE
</div>
```