# Start CSS transition when reach the div (or image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already search for that, but didn't find much information about it. It's possible to create and CSS transition with :hover effect, for example:

`div { color: red;} 
div:hover {color: blue;}`

And you just have to add the transition to this CSS. But I want that the trigger to start animation is when the DIV show up in the screen.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774089/jquery-detect-if-an-element-is-visible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is using a function to check if the element in question is in view when you scroll the page.

```
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

        var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

        return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
    }

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        if (isScrolledIntoView('.class') === true) {
            $('.class').addClass('in-view')
        }

    });
```

*code from:* [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

This code will add a class "in-view" if ".class" is visible after scrolling down. Based on this class you can add you css transition, for example:

```
   .class {
      opacity:0;
      transition:all 0.5s;
   }

    .class.in-view {
       opacity:1;
    }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z3xTU/  (scroll down)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I will check if it will work where I need.

Comment: I tried myself, didn't work as expected. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/eudennis/s8qjX/

Btw, is possible to change the addClass to toggleClass to remove the class when it's nos visible?

Comment: @euDennis Hey man, i'm happy to help but first fix the error's in your code and include jquery.

Comment: I added the jquery but forgot to update. What error did you mean?

Comment: I forgot to answer, but it worked after some tries ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't make that happen purely based upon CSS.  Look in to adding the animation via JQuery on document load (or whatever event you want).

for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.divSelectorGoesHere').animate({
      // Your css "property":"value"
  });
}
```