# Finding a visible class element within a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I find a visible child element within a parent with jQuery?

Tried e.g. the following (and many others) which does not work.

```
var childelement = $("#parent").find(".child:visible");
```

There are many child elements within the parent, but only one is visible in the same time. All child elements are defined with the same class name.

Edit:
 In my code the child elements are defined to visible or invisible with the display attribute. Similar than below:

```
<span class="child" style="display: inline;">One</li>
<span class="child" style="display: none;">Two</li>
```

SOLUTION
Got it work with this one:

```
<div class="child" style="display: inline;">One</li>
<div class="child" style="display: none;">Two</li>
```

Comment: I added some more code to my example. See above.

Comment: Actually I used the span element in the beginning. There were problems with that one. Changed it to div and now it works. I didn't copypaste the whole code here because it's quite complex. Now it works. See above. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it :

```
$('#parent').find(':visible');
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqc4v/)**

Comment: But I would like to find a .child class that is visible. There can be other visible elements within #parent as well. Your code is good, but it finds all classes within #parent that are visible.

Comment: Ok then when I use your example it still works : http://jsfiddle.net/xqc4v/1/

Comment: In my code the child elements are defined to visible or invisible with the display attribute. As seen below:
<li class="child" style="display: inline;">One</li>
<li class="child" style="display: none;">Two</li>

Comment: Ok but it's still working : http://jsfiddle.net/xqc4v/5/ If it works for you please take a two seconds to accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something along the lines of:

- Get all the child class elements of the parent element

  ```
  var childElements = $("#parent .child");
  ```
- Find the element you want:

  ```
  var foundIt;

  childElements.each(function(){ 

   if(this.is(':visible')){

      foundIt = this;

   }

  });
  ```

References:

- https://api.jquery.com/each/
- [Detect if an element is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774089/jquery-detect-if-an-element-is-visible)

EDIT:

```
  if(this.is(':inline')){

        foundIt = this;

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqc4v/4/)

```
$("#parentElement").children(':visible');
```