# Add custom property in attributes magento

Tags: jquery, magento

In magento, in my page product, I have all my products and I can filters them.
I display about 10 filters and I want to show only 5 and hide 5, I can do that in jQuery with .show()/.hide().
Display is not the problem, th problem is how I can know if the filter is visible or not.

I think I need to add a custom property to attributes, but I don't know how do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure this is what you are asking, but if you want to give a product a new attribute, you first

- Go to catalog - attributes - manage attributes.
- Click "Add new attribute"
- Fill in the details for the type of attribute you want.  You probably just want a dropdown with the values of "show" and "hide"
- For the sake of this example, we will assume you have filled in the attribute code as "newattribute"

Now, you can add this to your products by

- Go to catalog - attributes - manage attributes sets and clicking the product type you want to add it to
- Drag and drop the new attribute from "unassigned attributes" area to the list of used attributes
- Click "Save Attribute Set"

Your new fields will now appear when you add a product.

To retrieve this information in your template, you should use the function along the lines of

```
$_newattribute=$_product->getNewattribute();
```

Newattribute will be the name of your attribute's code.

( Note that the $_product object will have to have been defined first - it should have been so on any page displaying a product )

Alternatively, if you mean you just want to use jquery to know if something is visible or not, there is a solution here: [Detect if an element is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774089/jquery-detect-if-an-element-is-visible)