# jQuery .removeClass and addClass

Tags: jquery

I cant remove or add the class within a `div` and trying to remove the class `.wew` when the `.st-collapse` is visible and add class `.wew1` if the `.st-collapse`
 is hidden

so my flow is go to each parent div and find its div child

my HTML

```html
    <div class="st">
      <div class="st-heading wew">
       <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-collapse">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="st">
          <div class="st-heading wew">
           <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          </div>
          <div class="st-collapse">
           <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a></li>
           </ul>
          </div>
         </div>
```

this is my script

```js
  jQuery(".st").each(function(){
      var s = jQuery(this).find(".st-collapse").is(":visible");
      if(s){
        jQuery(this).find(".st-heading").removeClass("wew");
      }else{
        jQuery(this).find(".st-heading").addClass("wew1");
      }
    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774089/detect-if-an-element-is-visible

Comment: What's the issue ? it seems working

Comment: @Loading.. yes that was i thought too but i doesnt remove or add the classes

Comment: @Loading.. that makes me wonder why it doesnt working

Comment: @zer00ne congratulations??

Comment: This only runs once during page load. It should work fine if it's placed at the end of the page. It works for me. If you're expecting it to work continuously, you'll have to come up with a way to trigger it when it needs to run.

Comment: @Ouroborus I put it at the end of the page too.

Comment: Okay, then it works. As I said, it will only run once.  It does remove `wew` from the particular elements.

Comment: nope it doesnt remove class

Comment: it's just adding class when not visible, use `jQuery(this).find(".st-heading").removeClass('wew').addClass("wew1");` instead of 
`jQuery(this).find(".st-heading").addClass("wew1");`

Comment: @Loading.. i got this error `SyntaxError: illegal character` at wew1

Comment: You must define what exactly "not working" means in the context of your particular situation. What do you expect it to do. What do you perceive it actually doing? Also it would be nice if we knew what the classes `.whe`atever so and so is as well.

Comment: @zer00ne i put different css in both `.wew` and `.wew1` for example I put `background:red` on `.wew` so the background in `.st-heading` become red if the `.st-collapse` is visible

Comment: i dont know why but it got working i just reverse the condition instead of `.is(".visible")` i make it `.is(":hidden")` and make the `if` addClass and `else` into removeClass

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in jQuery it goes `.is(":visible");` with a colon `:` not a period `.` Nevertheless I'm glad you have resolved your dilemma, happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure (I'm probably 70% sure actually) about what your problem is, since you posted a statement and not a question. So let me know if I'm way off or close or whatever.

The classes were not provided and I assume it must be of some importance since we are dealing with `visibility` and two classes(probably with diametrically opposed properties involving either `display`,`visibility`, and/or `opacity`. So I made my own classes `.off` and `.on`.

```
    .st-heading.on + .st-collapse {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .st-heading.off + .st-collapse {
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

The classes in question belong to `.st-header` so I added the `+` adjacent sibling selector to indicate that the visibility of `.st-collapse` hinges upon whether `.st-heading` is `.off` or `.on`. I shortened the jQuery by:

1. ...removing `.each()` because with jQuery you don't need to be specific in simple cases. `$('.st-heading')` will find each `.st-heading` on the page as well...
2. ...replacing `add/removeClass()` with `toggleClass()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .st-heading.on + .st-collapse {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .st-heading.off + .st-collapse {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="st">
    <div class="st-heading off">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="st-collapse">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="st">
    <div class="st-heading on">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="st-collapse">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub-Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub-Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Sub-Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script>
    $(".st-heading").toggleClass('on off');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is working fine

> check the bin at [Working Demo of Code](https://jsbin.com/civokolube/edit?html,css,js,output)

I have did that at click event! Check!

**`Maybe jQuery is missing`** in your page

Comment: jQuery is in my page i had slider and carousel

Comment: Hey PRO, can you paste the the page and whole Browser console output? That may help!!!

Comment: i just change my condition into `.is(":hidden")` and reverse the output I dont know why it work