# How to get the eq of visible list in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the index of the list that is visible in jQuery and store it in a variable? So for the instance slideshow below:

1. I create a variable currSlides.
2. I store the index of the visible li into currSlides
3. currSlides should output as 3.
4. I will use that number to manipulate the slides.

   ```
   <ul class="slides-container">
     <li style="display:none">Image 1</li>
     <li style="display:none">Image 2</li>
     <li>Image 3</li>
     <li style="display:none">Image 4</li>
   </ul>
   ```

Comment: What do you mean by "get the eq"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-hidden-in-jquery) (which is the duplicate of [Detect if an element is visible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8774089/215552))

Comment: Mike I'm not detecting if element is visible and I don't see that as a duplicate. I've reworded my question. Appreciate if you could help me if you're willing to. Thanks.

Comment: Try index method in jQuery object as my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var currSlides  = $('.slides-container li').index($('.slides-container li:visible'));
```

```js
var currSlides  = $('.slides-container li').index($('.slides-container li:visible'));

alert(currSlides);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides-container">
  <li style="display:none">Image 1</li>
  <li style="display:none">Image 2</li>
  <li>Image 3</li>
  <li style="display:none">Image 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
var currSlides  = $('.slides-container').find('li:visible');
```

And also this

```
var currSlides = $('.slides-container li:visible');
```

[Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/e9tht700/)

Comment: It returns me 1. I need the index actually.