# How do I make an if statement using an element in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

So, I'm trying to make it so that when an element (inside the iframe) becomes hidden (display: none), it would make the iframe have display none.

I've tried:

```
var iframe = $('.preloader').contents().find('*');

if((iframe).is(':hidden')) {
  $('.preloader').css('display','none');
}
```

and

```
if($('.preloader').contents().find('*').is(':hidden')) {
  $('.preloader').css('display','none');
}
```

These both do not work.

HTML

```
<iframe class="preloader" src="https://sorrycantsay.net/preloader"></iframe>
```

This may help:

[Detect if an element is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774089/detect-if-an-element-is-visible)

[Selecting an element in iFrame jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316979/selecting-an-element-in-iframe-jquery)

Comment: Preloaders in iframe? That's something new for me  >_<

Comment: Sounds like what you're trying to do would violate Same Origin Policy - unless your iframe is on the same domain as your parent site? If it's not, you're probably out of luck..

Comment: @AlexanderYakushev | The preloader uses canvas which for some reason doesn't work.

Comment: @BradSullivan | I own both sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for me when working with iframes is using the [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) method + the `onmessage` event. It enables easy communication between iframe and parent.
Additional examples here: https://javascript.info/cross-window-communication#postmessage

Comment: Can I have an example of how this would be done?

    I need to check if an element in the iframe is hidden, if so, make the iframe display as none