# In IE7 SomeElement : visible not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

In by below code i am trying to check whether there are any Li that is visible. that well help me to determine whether to display some message or not.

but li:visible is not working in IE 7

```
function MangeEmptyRecordList() {
    var leftPanel = $('#' + firstContainer);
    var rightPanel = $('#' + secondContainer);
    var firstContainerList = leftPanel.find('li:visible');
    if (firstContainerList.length > 0) {
        $("#emptyFirstContainer").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#emptyFirstContainer").show();
    }
}
```

what is the alternate of :visible for IE7.

PS: In some situation there are some Li that are invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of jQuery, 1.7.1?

Moreover, "visible" generally refers to visibility:hidden; or opacity:0; although it should refer ti display:none; as well.  Where as hide() and show() generally refer to display:none; Although both should work, try the selector :hidden; instead to see if you have any luck.

Finally, another Stack Overflow [discussion mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178344/879354) that :visible doesn't work in functions.  Although it was written in 2008, hence it working in all other browsers, but could plausibly be the issue for IE7.  There have been [several other issues](http://remysharp.com/2008/10/17/jquery-really-visible/) with that selector in the past, but I would assume they've been fixed.  But again, hopefully :hidden will work.

If none of those work, there's several other ways to accomplish the same thing, but with much less elegance.  Hopefully one of the above bears some fruit.