# Ending SetInterval Function when leaving page in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, webcam, setinterval

I am putting together a jquery mobile site that includes several separate pages (*.htm) for webcams.  On those page, I am loading a set interval function that refreshes the image grab from the camera every few seconds and simulates video.

The problem occurs however when I navigate away from the webcam page (webcam.htm) using a nav link or back button back to index.htm,  the webcam.htm page remains in the DOM and keeps pulling the images every few seconds.

How can I clear the page or at least endinterval when the user leaves?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function camfresh() {
        setInterval(function(){ $("#rmcam").attr("src", "image.jpg?"+new Date().getTime());},2000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: A quick-and-dirty solution, if you don't want to mess up with listeners, could be to clear the interval inside the interval if a certain condition happens (in this case if the page is not visible anymore. For visibility question see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pageshow` and `pagehide` events to start and stop the interval:

```
var myInterval;
$(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'pageshow', function () {

    //note that `this` refers to the current `data-role="page"` element

    //cache `this` for later (inside the setInterval anonymous function)
    var $this = $(this);

    myInterval = setInterval(function(){
        $this.find("#rmcam").attr("src", "image.jpg?"+new Date().getTime());
    }, 2000);
}).delegate('.ui-page', 'pagehide', function () {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
});
```

You can change the `.ui-page` selectors to be more specific (currently they will select every pseudo-page).

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, looks like the interval is loading and firing but I am getting TypeError: $this.find is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$this.find("#rvcam").attr("src", "image.jpg?"+new Date().getTime());

#webcams (line 19)

TypeError: $this.find is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$this.find("#rvcam").attr("src", "image.jpg?"+new Date().getTime());  Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, `.find()` is a method that has to be run on a jQuery object since it's a jQuery function. I only cached `this` rather than `$(this)`. I edited the question with this fix.