# How to check if a div is visible state or not?

Tags: jquery

I have tabs like this.

```
<li id="singlechatpanel-1" style="visibility: hidden;">
     //content
</li>
```

Trying to check it like this:

```
$(".subpanel a").click(function() 
     {
        var chatterNickname = $(this).text();

        if(!$("#singlechatpanel-1").is(':visible'))
        {
            alert("Room 1 is filled.");
            $("#singlechatpanel-1").css({'visibility':'visible'});
            $("#singlechatpanel-1 #chatter_nickname").html("Chatting with: " + chatterNickname);
        }
```

If condition always returns false. How can I check visibility state of this div?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`is(':visible')` checks the `display` property of an element, you can use `css` method.

```
if (!$("#singlechatpanel-1").css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
   // ...
}
```

If you set the `display` property of the element to `none` then your `if` statement returns `true`.

Comment: One question on why we can't just use $('..').css('display')  and check for none? CSS newbie here, so not sure :S

Comment: @bitanath Please check this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Answer (score 57):

#### Check if it's visible.

`$("#singlechatpanel-1").is(':visible');`

#### Check if it's hidden.

`$("#singlechatpanel-1").is(':hidden');`

Answer (score 17):

if element is hide by jquery then use

```
if($("#elmentid").is(':hidden'))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to get the value of "visibility":

```
 if( ! ( $("#singlechatpanel-1").css('visibility') === "hidden")){
 }
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 4):

```
if (!$('#singlechatpanel-1').css('display') == 'none') {
   alert('visible');
}else{
   alert('hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use (':hidden') method to find if your div is visible or not..
Also its a good practice to cache a element if you are using it multiple times in your code..

```
$(".subpanel a").click(function() 
     {
        var chatterNickname = $(this).text();
        var $chatPanel = $("#singlechatpanel-1");

        if(!$chatPanel.is(':hidden'))
        {
            alert("Room 1 is filled.");
            $chatPanel.show();
            $("#singlechatpanel-1 #chatter_nickname").html("Chatting with: " + chatterNickname);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your `li` to a class, and do `$(".myclass").hide();` at the start to hide it instead of the visibility style attribute.

As far as I know, jquery uses the `display` style attribute to show/hide elements instead of visibility (may be wrong on that one, in either case the above is worth trying)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by any of these **two ways:**

```
$("#elementId").css('visibility')
and
$("#elementId").is(':visible');
```

if your element is **visible** then

```
$("#elementId").css('visibility') will return "visible"
and
$("#elementId").is(':visible') will return true
```

but if your element is **NOT visible** then

```
$("#elementId").css('visibility') will return undefined
and
$("#elementId").is(':visible') will return false
```