# visible div in swiper

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am using [Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php)(Default) in my application. I want to know which div is currently visible. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353741/how-to-check-if-a-div-is-visible-state-or-not) example but no use. I want to load data on `div` which is currently visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this may be help you

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php

mySwiper.activeSlide - returns the index number of currently active slide. Deprecated! Use .activeIndex

mySwiper.activeIndex - returns the index number of currently active slide. New in 1.9.2

Comment: can I load `html` into `div` based on this swipe index number?

Comment: see slide.html(innerHTML) [innerHTML - string] - works similar to jQuery/Zepto .html() function. If you specify innerHTML then it will replace slide's inner html and function will return slide instance. If innerHTML is not specified then this function will return slide's inner html.

Comment: See properly api link given by me you will get all the answer

Comment: Yes. Thank you...
Every thing is listed in this page... :)