# Detect if a form is visible or not

Tags: javascript

I have this scenario, I am detecting all forms on a site: `document.forms`

And I am trying to detect which forms are visible and which are not visible.

```
var formElement = []
for (i=0,l=document.forms.length;i<l;i++){
   var formIndex = document.forms.item(i);
   if (<need here just visible forms>){
       formElement.push(formIndex);
  }
}
```

Just to say I am doing this over an other pop up window that is communicating with the browser window with that forms, this depends on jQuery being present on the host site so jQuery is not a solution.

What is the best way to do this.

Comment: Loop through those and check .style

Comment: See update #4 in my answer - if hosts are different for opener and pop-up windows, you'll not able to do this. But you can do it as I showed for windows from same host.

Answer (score 3):

`var isVisible = form.style.display != 'none';`

**UPDATE #1: `hidden` attribute**

Also the element can be invisible if [`hidden`](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_global_hidden.asp) attribute is specified, so the condition
could be changed to

`var isVisible = form.style.display != 'none' && !form.hasAttribute('hidden');`

**UPDATE #2: jQuery approach:**

Find all invisible forms:

`$('form:hidden');`
or
`$('form:not(:visible)');`

Find all visible forms:

`$('form:visible');`

Check is form visible:

`$(form).is(':visible');`

**UPDATE #3: particular case (for original code in question)**

It's working pretty well to determine visible forms using a function from my demo:

```
function isVisible(el) {
    return el.style.display != 'none' && !el.hidden;
}

var formElement = [];
for (i=0, l=document.forms.length; i<l; i++) {
    var formIndex = document.forms.item(i);
    if(isVisible(formIndex)) {
        formElement.push(formIndex);
    }
}
console.log(formElement);
```

It's the same loop is this one in demo:

```
for(var i = document.forms.length; 0 < i--;) {
    log('Form #' + i + ': ' + isVisible(document.forms[i]));
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/FfSfw/)**

**UPDATE #4: pop-up window**

I've adapted my example for pop-up window, but I have to say that you're **NOT ABLE** to deal with elements in document from other host - **both pop-up and opener windows should belong to same host**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var wnd = window.open('popup.html');

    function isVisible(el) {
        return el.style.display != 'none' && !el.hidden;
    }
    wnd.onload = function() {
        /* This is working pretty well: */
        var formElement = [];
        console.log(wnd.document.forms);
        for (i=0,l=wnd.document.forms.length;i<l;i++){
           var formIndex = wnd.document.forms.item(i);
           console.log(formIndex);
           if (isVisible(formIndex)){
               formElement.push(formIndex);
               console.log('Form ' + formIndex.id + ' is visible');
          }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your comment doesn't give any valuable information. Can you edit your question and show the snippet of your code related to the task?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my demo and added your code snippet into it and it's working pretty well. Why are you saying that you are not seeing effects? Do you see any errors in console output? The code is working (yours and mine), so if you'll find any errors in console, you need to debug some other parts of your application.

Comment: your code is perfect. Like you said it is working. But the problem is that on more forms people hide the forms not with hidden element or with the style element style="display: none;". Try on this form: https://member.webmd.com/register.aspx?returl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webmd.com%2F&appid=1 there you have one form that is not visible it is hidden, and such forms make my problem above.

Comment: I've just went trough all forms on that page and found only 3 forms and all of them are visible: http://goo.gl/kbE2g

Comment: The problem is that the forms are visible, but i just need the forms that are really visible to the user (forms that the user can see with his eye) not all the visible forms to the browser, that is the problem now.

Comment: So you can also check does form have any elements except of `<input type="hidden" />`, is form in visible area (e.g. not `position: absolute; left: -1000px`) and so on.
Really it's not a common case so you have to analyze that page and develop rules that will describe how to determine is the form visible for user's eye or not.

Answer (score 1):

var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");

Then, you can loop through the array and check to see if the tag is visible or not.

Comment: the problem is that I can not use any $('any') coding.

Comment: Perhaps remove the jQuery tag if you're not able to use jQuery…

Comment: for (i=0,l=document.forms.length;i<l;i++){
            var formIndex = document.forms.item(i);
            formIndex.<NO ACTION THAT will give me if the form is visible or not>
        }

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$(element).is(":visible") // Checks for display:[none|block], ignores visible:[true|false]
```

Ref.  [How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
$('#form').is(':visible')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will go through all forms and tell which ones are visible and which aren't:

```
$("form").each(function() {
   if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
       console.log("Visible: ", this);
   } else {
       console.log("Hidden: ", this);
   }
});
```

or if you want to get all visible ones at once:

```
$("form:visible")
```

And the hidden ones:

```
$("form:hidden")
```