# How do i test if something is hidden with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, visibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testing if something is hidden with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery)

In jQuery, suppose you have an element of some kind that you're hiding and showing, using `.hide()`, `.show()` or `.toggle()`. How do you test to see if that element is currently hidden or visible on the screen?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try

```
$("some-selector").is(':hidden');
```

or

```
$("some-selector").is(':visible');
```

Here are the docs for the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selectors.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('.target').is(':hidden') // returns true if the element is hidden
$('.target').is(':visible') // returns true if the element is visible
```