# find element is hidden or not

Tags: jquery

I have some labels on my html page, I use them for validation errors, If all the input data is right then I hide those labels, and if not, showing accordingly. I want, if any of the label is shown then, disable the submit button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [.is(":visible")](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to find if an element is visible.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
     if($('label:visible').length)
      {
          //disable the submit button here
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

try `:visible` to check if it is not hidden  and `length()` to count the elements

```
if($('label:visible').length)..
```