# Check div visibility not display in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement, visibility

I've been trying everything and reading everywhere and can't seem to get this to work. What the heck am I doing wrong...

```
var visibility = $('#short-link').css('visibility');
$('#share-link span').click(function() {
    if (visibility != 'hidden'){
        $('#short-link').css({visibility: 'visible'});
    } else {
        $('#short-link').css({visibility: 'hidden'})
    }
});
```

Please help

Comment: Have you seent this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery

Comment: don't you need to have like this `$('#short-link').css({'visibility': 'visible'});`?single quotes on visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine this isn't behaving as you expect because you're defining visibility *outside* your function, so it never changes. I think you intended to write:

```
$('#share-link span').click(function() {
    var visibility = $('#short-link').css('visibility');
    if (visibility != 'hidden'){
        $('#short-link').css({visibility: 'visible'});
    } else {
        $('#short-link').css({visibility: 'hidden'})
    }
});
```

or better, cache the object but not the property:

```
var $shortLink = $('#short-link');
$('#share-link span').click(function() {
    var visibility = $shortLink.css('visibility');
    if (visibility != 'hidden'){
        $shortLink.css({visibility: 'visible'});
    } else {
        $shortLink.css({visibility: 'hidden'})
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, don't why I didin't catch that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#share-link span').click(function() {
    this.style.visibility = this.style.visibility == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
});
```

This avoids using jQuery methods to update the inline style of the node, and avoids setting a needless variable (which then has to be updated as the visibility changes).

> This seems way better from what your saying, I haven't messed around with pure JS yet, just jQuery. So instead of "this", wouldn't I use #short-link? Do I make it a javascript object?

If you'd rather stay with a more jQuery approach then I'd suggest:

```
$('#share-link span').click(function() {
    $(this).css('visibility', function(i,v){
        return v == 'visible' ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    });
});
```

Assuming, of course, that it's the `span` you wish to act on.

Comment: This seems way better from what your saying, I haven't messed around with pure JS yet, just jQuery. So instead of "this", wouldn't I use #short-link? Do I make it a javascript object? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the visibility outside of the event handler, so it won't really change by itself.

In addition to Dave's answer, if you just want to toggle the visibility of the element, `.toggle` might work:

```
$('#share-link span').click(function() {
    $('#short-link').toggle();
});
```

The difference between your approach and this one is that `.toggle()` toggles between `display: none` and your original `display` value instead of changing the `visibility` property.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing quotes on visiblity

```
$('#short-link').css('visibility','visible');
```

or

```
 $('#short-link').css({'visibility':'visible'});
```

Comment: You missed the {}. Also while you're right that this can cause issues on some browsers (older IE versions, I believe), I don't think it's the problem here.

Comment: my mistake; just checked the docs and your version is fine. I still don't think it's the issue though!

Comment: I am not sure what is the mistake. But I caught quotes thing when i saw the code.If We see the `HTML` of those `ID`s OP used in the script we can tell.