# JQuery if / else with show/hide

Tags: jquery, class, if-statement, show-hide

I have some divs (`title`). When I press, lets say `div1`, the subtitle shows. And when I press another div, lets say `div2`, then `div1` hides, and `div2` are being showed.

What I want, is when I press `div1`, and then press `div1` again, it hides.
You can see in the if/else statement what I've tried.

Hope someone can help me here.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".title").click(function()
    {
        var $element = $(this);

        $(".open").removeClass("open");
        $('.subtitle').hide(500);

        $element.toggleClass('open');
        $element.children('.subtitle').toggle(500);

        if($(this).hasClass() == "open")
        {
            $element.children(".subtitle").hide(500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML code as well?

Comment: can you create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this).hasClass() == "open"` should be `$(this).hasClass('open')`

and inside the `if` shouldn't you show the subtitle instead of hiding it?

Answer (score 1):

Toggle is the correct approach in this instance.

You might also want to check out this
[Visibility/Hidden info.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/178325/2136123/)

It covers how you could check for CSS visibility, CSS display, as well as actual element visibility. From those you can do any standard conditional statements depending on the "hiding" in question. Some may work better than others in certain circumstances.