# Checking visibility of an element

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scrollto

I want to check if an element is visible and if yes, I want to scroll down to it. I am trying to achieve that with the following jquery:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if(j('#element').css('display') == 'block'){
        j('body').scrollTo('#target');
      };
});
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
// jQuery no conflict mode
var j = $.noConflict();

// retain meaning of jQuery's handle (optional but makes it
// sometimes easier if you don't use one-letter assignments
// of jQuery)
(function($){

  // document read
  $(function(){
    // if element is visible (a visible #element was found)
    if $('#element:visible').size() > 0){
      // scroll to #target
      $('body').scrollTo('#target');
    }
  });

})(j);
```

`:visible` makes it easier. You're can't just test against `display=='block'`, you'd also have to test for `inline-block` and others in addition to checking the `visibility` setting. For example, the element could have `display:block:visibility:hidden` which doesn't make it `:visible`.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
if($(element).is(":visible"))
```

Refer to this post: [How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(function($) {
    if($('#element').is(':visible')){
        $('body').scrollTo('#target');
    };
});
```