# represent a hide/show value inside an if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, boolean, hide, show

I have a script when there is a toggle that make a div hide or show, using the .hide and .show
I need to make another script when there is an if statement that happens only when the div is shown.

**this is the script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#click1').toggle(function(){
    $('#div1').show().animate({'height': '50%'}, 400);
  }, function(){
    $('#div1').animate({'height': '0px'}, 400).hide(0);
  });
  });
</script>
```

I need to add an if statment like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#click1').toggle(function(){
    if (div2==show)
    {
      $('#div2').animate({'height': '0px'}, 400).hide(0);
    }
    $('#div1').show().animate({'height': '50%'}, 400);
  }, function(){
    $('#div1').animate({'height': '0px'}, 400).hide(0);
  });
  });
</script>
```

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing if something is hidden with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated code to handle `visibility` and `0 height` as suggested by @mplungjan and @Frexuz:

```
var div2 = $('#div2');
if (div2.is(':visible') && div2.height() > 0) {
    $('#div2').animate({'height': '0px'}, 400).hide(0);
}
```

Comment: What if it has visibility:"hidden" or just 0 height?

Comment: This is a little bit better `if ($('#div2').is(":visible"))`, but it won't check for 0 height i think.

Comment: @Frexuz answer updated for `is(":visible")`, @mplungjan what you suggest for 0 height? Should I add height check like this `$('#div2').height() > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide another div while showing one div, right?

No need to add if statement, just give a class `.content` to all of your content div and hide it.

*You can also use `slideUp` and `slideDown` instead of animate.

Check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/8JQXB/1/

### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.link').on('click', function () {
        $('.content').slideUp(500);
        $('div#' + $(this).attr('target')).css({
            'height': '50%'
        }).slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<a class="link" target="div1">Click1</a><br />
<div id="div1" class="content">Div 1 content</div>
<a class="link" target="div2">Click2</a><br />
<div id="div2" class="content">Div 2 content</div>
<a class="link" target="div3">Click3</a><br />
<div id="div3" class="content">Div 3 content</div>
```