# How to check if an element in DOM is hidden or not by query a class?

Tags: jquery, css, file

Given the element below ("FileToUpload"), how do I test if its class is set to block or none?

**HTML**

```html
<div id=\ "FileToUploadLabel\">File:</td>
    <td colspan=\ "1\">
</div>
<input type=\ "file\" id=\ "FileToUpload\" name=\ "FileToUpload\" size=\ "70\"/>
```

**JS**

```js
//To show the file control: 
$("#FileToUpload").css("display", "block");

//To hide the file control: 
$("#FileToUpload").css("display", "none");
```

Basically I need to test it in a conditional statement like this:

```js
if ("FileToUpload not hidden" && $("#FileToUpload").val() == "") 
{
  Alert("An file needs to be uploaded when File tag is being displayed.");
  return;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest way is to use the built in ":visible" selector in jquery

```
if($("#FileToUpload").is(":visible") && $("#FileToUpload").val() == ""){
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Sure thing! And as someone else mentioned, using jquery's built in `hide()` and `show()` is simpler than using `css('display', 'block')` to show and hide elements @Max

Answer (score 1):

See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery). Use `$(element).is(":visible")` to check if it is hidden or not. Also, you can use `.hide()` and `.show()` to more easily hide and show elements.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work for you:

```
var currDisplay = $("#FileToUpload").css("display");


if (currDisplay != "none" && $("#FileToUpload").val() == "") 
{
  Alert("An file needs to be uploaded when File tag is being displayed.");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/178386/1046057) You can use the [`:hidden`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/hidden) selector:

```
if($('#FileToUpload:hidden').length && $("#FileToUpload").val()){
    Alert("An file needs to be uploaded when File tag is being displayed.");
    return;
}
```