# Checking div.contents() for presence of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a piece of javascript which allows for the selection of multiple choices.   An example of the html is this:

Pick an option:

```
<br><br>

<div id="dialogue_container"> </div>
<div id="Append"> And then this happens.</div>          

<div class="inlinechoice-0" id="0">
    <a class="question" id="1">Choice 1</a><br>
    <a class="question" id="2">Choice 2</a><br>
    <a class="question" id="3">Choice 3</a>
</div>

<div class="answer-1">
    You picked 1.  
    <div class="inlinechoice-1" id="1">
        <a class="question" id="4">Choice 4</a><br>
        <a class="question" id="5">Choice 5</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="answer-2">
    You picked 2. 
</div>
<div class="answer-3">
    You picked 3. 
</div>
<div class="answer-4">
    You picked 4. 
    <div class="inlinechoice-2" id="2">
        <a class="question" id="6">Choice 6</a><br>
        <a class="question" id="2">Choice 7 (2)</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="answer-5">
    You picked 5. 
</div>
<div class="answer-6">
    You picked 6. 
</div>
<br><br>

<FORM>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Refresh">
</FORM>
```

Then I have some javascript here:

```
$('div[class*=inlinechoice').on('click','.question', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
    $id = $this.prop('id');

    $("#dialogue_container").append($('.answer-' + $id).contents());
});

$('div[class*=inlinechoice').on('click', function(a) {
    var $this = $(this),
    $cid = $this.prop('id');

    $('.inlinechoice-' + $cid).hide();

});
```

And then a little bit of CSS here:

```
div[class*='inlinechoice-'] { cursor: pointer; }

div[class*='answer-'] {display:none}

div[class*='append']{display:none}
```

The way it works is that all of the inlinechoice/answerclass/append class begin as hidden.  As the user clicks the options, the javascript puts the appropriate answers into the dialogue_container div in the order that they are selected.  However, I would like to add a final touch, and that is to show the contents of the append div once there are no more choices available to the user.  I need to check the contents of the dialogue_container to see if there are any active inlinechoices(i.e. non hidden ones), and if there are none, then I can set the append div to be shown.  I'm thinking the solution will be something like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-with-jquery), but I'm not sure how to apply this to the contents of the dialogue container, as they are dynamic.

Thanks.

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/bawpie/pen/itbvq)

Edit:  New Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/bawpie/pen/AwmBJ).  I've added the following code to the first question onclick event and it's appending correctly to choices which have no nested choices (i.e. choices 2 and 3) in them, but not choice 1 (which has additional questions).  I think rather than searching the entire contents of #dialogue_container, I need to just look at the contents of the last select #answer, however, this is proving a bit tricky.

```
    $foo = $("#dialogue_container").append($('.answer-' + $id).contents());

            $str = $foo.html();

            $term = "question";
            $index = $str.indexOf($term);
            if($index != -1){
            //Do Nothing
            }
            else{
            $('#append').show();
            }
```

Edit:  Is there a particular reason why this works:

```
        $foo = $("#dialogue_container").append($('.answer-' + $id).contents());
```

But this doesn't?

```
        $('.answer-' + $id).contents();
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with using .contents() combined with a class rather than a div, but I'm not sure how to instruct the script to return just the contents of the last clicked answer class.

If I add the following in, I can get an alert to return the correct contents, but I don't want to hardcode the answer-id class like this:

```
  alert($('[class*="answer-2"]').eq(0).html());
```

I've tried:

```
  alert($('[class*="answer-"]' + $id).eq(0).html());
```

To try and pick up the correct answer class, but it doesn't return anything.  I feel like I'm nearly there on this, but not quite!

Edit: Thanks to a little clarification [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107223/how-to-display-contents-of-selected-class-jquery), I finally managed to figure this out! I'll add the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the order in which I called things mattered (you'd think I'd be able to figure something like this out by now).

Adding the following into the javascript right after $id variable has been defined seems to have done the trick:

```
    //This is the append code which adds the contents of the append div when there are no more choices.
    $str = $('.answer-' + $id).html();
    $index = $str.indexOf("question");

    if ($index != -1) {
        //Do Nothing
    } else {
    $('#append').show();
    }
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/bawpie/pen/AwmBJ)

Answer (score 1):

Missing `]` in your **[attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

```
$('div[class*=inlinechoice]').on('click', '.question', function(e) {
    //               -----^-----
    var $this = $(this),
            $id = $this.prop('id');
    $("#dialogue_container").append($('.answer-' + $id).contents());
});
$('div[class*=inlinechoice]').on('click', function(a) {
    //               -----^-----
    var $this = $(this),
            $cid = $this.prop('id');
    $('.inlinechoice-' + $cid).hide();
});
```

<kbd>[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjBEz)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, would I need to add one to the first choice as well (in the first line of the code)?

Comment: @bawpie : oh sorry I just missed that one

Comment: No worries, it seemed sensible that I'd need to do them on both but just wanted to check (I'm very new at this!)