# jQuery .toggle( showOrHide ) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use .toggle( showOrHide ) function to check the status. In the api documentation, it is mentioned as;

> ```
> $( "#foo" ).toggle( showOrHide );
> if ( showOrHide === true ) {
>     $( "#foo" ).show();
> } else if ( showOrHide === false ) {
>     $( "#foo" ).hide();
> }
> ```

But its not working. Anybody knows how to make it work? I want to check the status whether its show or hide.

Comment: what is the value of `showOrHide `?

Comment: I got null value. I've initialized the variable "showOrHide", but it does not return anything.

Comment: "*It's not working*" tells us nothing about how you're calling the `toggle()` method and gives us nothing on which we can post an answer explaining why it's not working, or how to make it work. Can you clearly show what you're trying to do, and what JavaScript/jQuery you're using, with what HTML? As it stands you seem to be using `toggle()` as a getter, which it doesn't really do. A live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo would likely be useful too.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

> The second version of the method accepts a Boolean parameter. If this parameter is true, then the matched elements are shown; if false, the elements are hidden. In essence, the statement:

You need to declare `true` or `false`;

```
var showOrHide = true;

if ( showOrHide === true ) {
    $( "#foo" ).show();
} else if ( showOrHide === false ) {
    $( "#foo" ).hide();
}
```

Using the shorthand would make sense in most cases, but it seems the OP has a requirement to check the status first.

Answer (score 1):

This is answer is predicated on my inferring your question to be:

> How do I assess whether something is shown or hidden?

This question *inferred* from [your comment to another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992555/jquery-toggle-showorhide-not-working#comment36972748_23992715):

> ... I want to check the toggle status is show or hide.

You're misunderstanding what `toggle(Boolean)` does; if you pass a Boolean that evaluates to `true` (or otherwise 'truthy') then it will show the element, otherwise a `false` (or 'falsey') value will hide the element(s) upon which `toggle()` was called.

To retrieve whether the element is shown, you should evaluate the Boolean itself (allowing for truthy/falsey values):

```
var isShown = showOrHide ? "Yes, it's shown" : "No, it's hidden";
```

Or, more strictly:

```
var isShown = showOrHide === true ? "Yes, it's shown" : "No, it's hidden";
```

You could also use jQuery's `.is(':visible')` which returns a Boolean value describing whether the element upon which it's called is visible to the user (`true`), or hidden (`false`):

```
var isShown = $('#element').is(':visible');
```

A very simple case, illustrating the use of `.is('visible')`:

```
$('#toggleControl').on('change', function(){
    $('#demo').toggle(this.checked);
    $('#status').text(function(){
        return $('#demo').is(':visible') ? 'Shown' : 'Hidden';
    });
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j6zWk/).

And, similarly, a demo testing the Boolean itself:

```
$('#toggleControl').on('change', function(){
    var checkbox = this;
    $('#demo').toggle(checkbox.checked);
    $('#status').text(function(){
        return checkbox.checked ? 'Shown' : 'Hidden';
    });
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j6zWk/1/).

Both demos operate on the following HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleControl" /><label for="toggleControl"> element</label>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="demo">
    <p>Can be shown or hidden, by checking, or unchecking, the checkbox.</p>
</div>
```

References:

- [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).
- [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

Where in the jQuery docs did you find this? A quick lookup suggests this is a method to show or hide an element, not to return whether or not the element is visible: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I've tried this but it return a null value and the toggle functionality not working when adding like this $( "#foo" ).toggle( showOrHide );

Answer (score 0):

Given an element

The code you supplied will work.

Create a function for it:

```
function showOrHide(element, display) {   
    if ( display === true ) {
        $(element ).show();
    } else if ( display === false ) {
        $(element).hide();
    }
}
```

And call it with foo

```
showOrHide($('#foo'), true);
showOrHide($('#foo'), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo link:  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/justinliang/qJLRk/).

I update the answer and pls check if it is the correct one you want.

Here is the example code:

```
var showOrHide = false;
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    showOrHide = !showOrHide;
    if ( showOrHide === true ) {
        $( "#foo" ).show();
    } else if ( showOrHide === false ) {
        $( "#foo" ).hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not expecting this type of answer. Because I want to check the toggle status is show or hide.

Answer (score 0):

you miss understood the api (check [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#entry-examples) - scroll few lines up to see it).
in the api it says that this `$( "#foo" ).toggle( showOrHide );` is equivalent to:

```
if ( showOrHide === true ) {
  $( "#foo" ).show();
} else if ( showOrHide === false ) {
  $( "#foo" ).hide();
}
```

as for using it: you need to set the value of the variable "showOrHide" to either "true" or "false", and then use `$( "#foo" ).toggle( showOrHide );`, when of course, you need to change the "#foo" to whatever your element is.

as for checking if the element is visible or hidden - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-using-jquery) link.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a variable to check your element's state:

```
var isShowing = true;

$('button').click(function () {
    if (isShowing) {
        $('#foo').hide();
        isShowing = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#foo').show();
        isShowing = true;
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyBV6/1/)** based on what @urbz posted previously...

Answer (score 0):

This may also help. as an alternative to the other answers

```
var showOrHide = !$( "#foo" ).is(':visible');
$( "#foo" ).toggle( showOrHide );
```