# jQuery toggle function hiding visible element even if parameter is truthy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992555/jquery-toggle-showorhide-not-working) is similar but does not help.

The jQuery docs indicate that the [`$.toggle` function](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) accepts a Boolean parameter:

> The second version of the method accepts a Boolean parameter. If this
>   parameter is true, then the matched elements are shown; if false, the
>   elements are hidden.

However, passing a truthy (non-Boolean) value doesn't seem to get recognized. The code below alternates between showing/hiding the red box even though the `toggle` function is passed a truthy value.

Why doesn't the truthy value work?

```js
var imageURL = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABBoAAAK8CAYAAABBSdyWAAAgAElEQVR4Ady9+bMcyXHn6ZWZdbwbaDSAvthNiocoiuRobU2/6P//ZW3X1mZNGo6GktjsE2gAD8c76q7Ktc/X41uZr/DQYLObnNEEUC8y4/Tw8PDw8PCIHPzmt//QRs9tBhFtm0H4g8FgF+vwqqrCv/V6rfh+ul2GP+FhsM387XYQbTuISlVXUdd11";

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".box").on("click", function() {
     $("#redBox").toggle(imageURL);
     $("#curURL").text(imageURL);     
   });
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;  
}

#redBox {
  background: red;
}

#blueBox {
  background: blue;
}

#curURL {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blueBox" class="box"></div>
<div id="redBox" class="box"></div>

<div id="curURL"></div>
```

[Codepen Mirror](https://codepen.io/Crashalot/pen/JjoRLBx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as using the double not operator (`!!`) as @MattU suggested - you can also use `Boolean(imageURL)`..

```js
var imageURL = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABBoAAAK8CAYAAABBSdyWAAAgAElEQVR4Ady9+bMcyXHn6ZWZdbwbaDSAvthNiocoiuRobU2/6P//ZW3X1mZNGo6GktjsE2gAD8c76q7Ktc/X41uZr/DQYLObnNEEUC8y4/Tw8PDw8PCIHPzmt//QRs9tBhFtm0H4g8FgF+vwqqrCv/V6rfh+ul2GP+FhsM387XYQbTuISlVXUdd11";

$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".box").on("click", function() {
     $("#redBox").toggle(Boolean(imageURL));
     $("#curURL").text(imageURL);     
   });
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;  
}

#redBox {
  background: red;
}

#blueBox {
  background: blue;
}

#curURL {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blueBox" class="box"></div>
<div id="redBox" class="box"></div>

<div id="curURL"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The second version of the method accepts a **Boolean** parameter.

Yes, and it's a strict Boolean type check. See here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/showHide.js#L86

If you want to toggle based on whether or not the `imageURL` is null/undefined, you can force it to evaluate as a boolean expression with the double bang operator `!!` like this:

```js
$("#redBox").toggle(!!imageURL);
```

You can read more about "double NOT" here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT

> It is possible to use a couple of NOT operators in series to explicitly force the conversion of any value to the corresponding boolean primitive.