# How to check if IFrame is visible on page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Suppose I have a page with multiple IFrames :

**Main Page**

```
<div id='someDiv1' style='display:none; '>
       <iframe id='iframe1' src='iframe1.html'>
           <input id='someinput'></input>
       </iframe>
</div>
```

**IFrame (iframe1.html)**

```
<input id='someinput'></input>
<script>
  function isElementVisible(elem){

  }
</script>
```

In this scenario how do i check if the element is visible/hidden due to the parent div of IFrame hiding it?

I tried using **$('#someinput').is(':visible')** but I always get true if I run it inside IFrame. I don't have an option to change the page structure nor execute the script inside parent.

Comment: In pure JavaScript `var is_hidden = parent.document.getElementById("iframe1").parentNode.style.display == "none"; alert(is_hidden ? "I am hidden" : "I am visible");`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing if something is hidden, using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/testing-if-something-is-hidden-using-jquery)

Comment: Not really a duplicate. Please read my complete question.

Comment: Its vanilla JS, you dont need Jquery for every single line of code you write.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The document inside your iframe is not aware of the situation in your main page... But I believe you can just 'query' your parent to check if it's visible?

```
$('#someDiv1', window.parent.document).is(":visible");
```

or without jquery because you don't really need it..

```
if(window.parent.document.getElementById("someDiv1").style.display != "none") 
    alert("Visible");
else 
    alert("Hidden");
```

Comment: Will this work if IFRAME is from other domain than parent document?

Comment: As @Gacek brought up, this will not work if the <iframe> is in another domain, at least not without a special cross-domain setup. Still upvoting because it's a good answer otherwise, though it shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you can access the value/properties of an element  within an iFrame 
I tried accessing the value but its gives "*undefined*"

[Jquery try accessing value from iframe container](http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/q5xW8/)

```
var isDivOpen = $("#someDiv1").is(":visible");
//for getting the state of the div : visible/hidden
```

Answer (score -1):

URL parameters are your friend.

in the iframe1.html put this at the top:

```
<script>

    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
    var test = getUrlVars();
    console.log(test[0]);

</script>
```

and for your main page use:

```
<div id='someDiv1' style='display:none; '>
    <iframe id='iframe1' src='iframe.html?visible=yes'>

    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I cant modify the document.