# Svg is :visible always returns true even when ancestors are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm making a tab set up and need to set display none on a container element, according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8266879/1213795 - is.(":visible") should return false if an ancestor is hidden right? So this should return false.

```
$('svg').each(function (i) {
    console.log("Doesn't work! - " + $(this).is(":visible"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/umkn1rmo/6/

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate the issue, it seems to work fine in Safari/Chrome.

Comment: So if it works fine, what's the problem?

Comment: Safari and Chrome aren't the only browsers

Comment: Definitely. So what's the problem?

Comment: Check the title name, it always returns true for svg even if ancestors are hidden. Seems to be the case for Firefox & IE

Comment: Aaaah so, that's the actual question! You have an issue in FF and IE. Why didn't you say so earlier :) We had to guess the question. Found something, I'm posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found out that the broken "hidden" selector for SVGs  is a known firefox bug... and won't be fixed : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12587 - concerning IE, it's almost certainly the same.