# correct use of .is(':visible')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
<div style="height:500px;display:none"></div>
<div style="height:1000px;"></div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

     var visible_elem_height = $('div').is(':visible').height()

     alert( visible_elem_height )

});

</script>
```

but my code Doesn't work , So what do u suggest ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if an element is hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/checking-if-an-element-is-hidden)

Comment: You have parenthesis `)` missing  at the end of `document.ready`

Comment: @Gideon Yea may be!! But if it is unknown then OP should correct that first before proceeding with the other tries!

Comment: Many post their answer, but I'm still here deciding whether to answer or maybe this is just a typo error?

Comment: Sorry for the silly question but, do you included already the jquery library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) return a boolean value so your script will fail, instead you need

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var visible_elem_height = $('div:visible').height();
    //or var visible_elem_height = $('div').filter(':visible').height()

    alert(visible_elem_height)

})
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('div').is(':visible')` returns true/false depending on the visibility of your element. On the other hand, `.height()` function is applied on the element and NOT on the `boolean` output. Therefore, `$('div').is(':visible').height()` will simply not work.

To achieve the desired behaviour, use the `:visible` selector `$('div:visible').height()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var visible_elem_height = $('div:visible').height()

     alert( visible_elem_height )

});
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ELcn1dqfJFQSdw9kag2I?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.filter()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div = $("div").filter(function(i, el) {
    return $(el).is(":visible")
  });
  
  if (div.length > 0) {
    alert(div.height())
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:500px;display:none"></div>
<div style="height:1000px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `is(':visible')` returns `true` or `false` as output. If you want to get the height of the element, you can directly get it using the `.height()` method.