# How to populate a JavaScript array with only the divs that have display:block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to populate an array in JavaScript using jQuery. I have some `<div>` elements in a `<section>` and I  **only want** the `<div>` elements that are visible (via CSS property `display: block`) to be added to the array.

**HTML:**

```
<section id="container">
    <div>shows up 1</div>
    <div style="display:none">doesn't show 2</div>
    <div>shows up 3</div>
    <div style="display:none">doesn't show 4</div>
    <div style="display:none">doesn't show 5</div>
    <div>shows up 6</div>
    <div>shows up 7</div>
    <div>shows up 8</div>
    <div style="display:none">doesn't show 9</div>
    <div>shows up 10</div>
</section>
```

**JavaScript / jQuery**

`var mainList = $("#container div");`

This currently gets ALL `<div>` elements regardless of their display. Is there some kind of filter I can put onto this call to get *only* the elements that are visible? It should only return the 6 `<div>` elements that say "shows up" in them.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/259chbj4/

Note: For this, I can't use a `class` that has `display: none`. I am looking for a solution that only modifies the JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if an element is hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/checking-if-an-element-is-hidden)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

```
$("#container div:visible");
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
 var mainList = $('#container').find("div :visible");
```