# detect visibility status of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I would like to detect whether an element is visible or hidden. I thought about this

```
$("#mobile_navbar:visible").change(function() {
   console.log("detected")
});
```

but this does not seem to work...? Any ideas how to do this? Basically I what to check whether $("#mobile_navbar").is( ":visible" ) has changed... but I want that a function is called whenever that happens, lick the .click() function which gets triggered if an element is clicked on.
thanks
carl

Comment: When you say "visible", do you mean the CSS property, or whether it's actually visible on the page? (Obviously it can be hidden by other means)

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? want to detect the change of visibility as an event?

Comment: I want to detect whether $("#mobile_navbar").is( ":visible" ) has changed...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if an element is hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/checking-if-an-element-is-hidden)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lru99de0/26/

Answer (score 0):

```
var isVisible = $("#mobile_navbar").css('display');
if(isVisible != 'none') {
   console.log("detected")
};
```

Comment: There is no `visible` CSS property, you may be looking for `visibility`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the element is visible on the screen, you can do like this :

```
if($(selector).css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
   doSomething
}
else{
  doSomethingElse
}
```