# Hide div when bootstrap toggle active

Tags: jquery

I want to hide a div, when bootstrap toggle div is active:

```
if($('data-toggle').is('collapse')){
    $("#Div1").hide();
} else{
    $("#Div1").show();
}
```

Comment: and your click event, or on toggle active event?

Comment: `is('collapse')` checks the _tagName_ of  the element! Also what should `$('data-toggle')` select?

Comment: on toggle active event @madalinivascu

Comment: can you post that code of that event?

Comment: why are you using custom html tags?

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-hidden-in-jquery

Comment: http://kunal.theanalyticshop.com/startf/add_product_type.html

Please Open in Device and you will see problem in overlapping menu

Comment: @AjayBijlani i don't see any overlapping menus

Comment: you have the checkboxes all mixed up, i don't think you are selecting the elements based on the clicked element

Comment: lol those aren't even checkboxes :))

Answer (score 0):

First you need to select via css selector using `$('.class')` , then check if it has the specified class.

Edit: For [Bootstraptoggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/)

```js
if($('.toggle').hasClass('off')){
    $("#Div1").hide();
}
else{
    $("#Div1").show();
}
```