# JQuery: if div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I'm using JS as a way of changing the content of an SPA I'm creating. When I press a button to change the content the HTML changes from this:

```html
<div id="selectDiv" style="display: none;">
```

to this:

```html
<div id="selectDiv" style>
```

Now part of my SPA has a div that contains a number of checkboxes, each representing a div, and so when I press the submit button, the next div that should be displayed will be the first item in the checkbox list that was selected.

I'm wondering if there's a way in JQuery for the code to "almost detect" which div is now visible. something like this:

```
if($('#selectDiv').isVisible()){
    //JS code associated with this div.
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you not mess around with the `.hasClass` function to do something like this? Check if an element has a certain class and then go from there?

Comment: `if(document.getElementById("selectDiv").style.display !== "none"){...}`

Comment: What do you mean by "almost detect"? You could use $elem.is(":visible") to determine is the element is visible!

Comment: check this one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72112111/14229690

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can use [`.is(':visible')`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

> Selects all elements that are visible.

For example:

```
if($('#selectDiv').is(':visible')){
```

Also, you can get the div which is visible by:

```
$('div:visible').callYourFunction();
```

Live example:

```js
console.log($('#selectDiv').is(':visible'));
console.log($('#visibleDiv').is(':visible'));
```

```css
#selectDiv {
  display: none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectDiv"></div>
<div id="visibleDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Hey there - not disputing the correctness of this answer, but please consider suggesting or voting on a dupe for questions like these. There are already some pretty comprehensive answers that exist on Stack Overflow that we can point this question to instead.

Comment: Could I do something like this?    $(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#selectDiv').is(':visible')) {
        //JS code associated with this div.
    }
});

Comment: Yes, see my update.

Comment: @JacksonSentzke any thoughts?

Comment: It runs in the code snippet, but it's not running in my code. It's now just trial and error to get it working.

Comment: @MoshFeu function visible() {
    if ($('#selectDiv ').is(':visible')) {
        $('#selectDiv ').append("<p>Test</p>");
    }
} I have the code wrapped in a function, I then just call the function.

Comment: If it's a question, the answer is yes. You can do that.

Comment: thank, it's work for me.

Comment: @Md. Ashiquzzaman glad to hear :)