# How to start this JQuery counter only when its containing DIV appears onscreen?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

On a Wordpress page, I have this code to start a count-up, but I only want it to start counting when the user has scrolled far enough down the page so that it appears onscreen (it's in a containing DIV called "three-counter-section").

How do you retrofit this code to enable that?

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
var $this = $(this),
countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
$({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
countNum: countTo
},

{ duration: 11000,
easing:'easeInOutCubic',
step: function() {
$this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
},
complete: function() {
$this.text(this.countNum);
}
});  
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery: if div is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468981/jquery-if-div-is-visible)

Comment: Not a duplicate of the proposed answer. That seems to apply only if something was visible/invisible via CSS (and I tried it anyway, but didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do following to trigger an event when any element is visible.

```
setInterval(function(){
  if($('.div1').is(':visible')){
    //do something
  }
  else {
    //do nothing..
  }      
}, 100);
```

** Change .div1 as you needed.

Comment: Thanks, but getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: That is when you don't include jQuery library, check if this code excutes after jQuery include.

Comment: JQuery is loaded in the head section, before this code is executed.

Comment: Hm. Still not working. This is the offending line of code: if($('.three-counter-section').is(':visible')){