# How to do this Javascript in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Javascript that checks if a field is empty.

```
function checkForm(form) {
    if(this.firstname.value == "") {
      alert("Please enter your First Name in the form");
      this.firstname.focus();
      return false;
    }
}
```

How would I rewrite this using jQuery?

Comment: show some effort, at least try something.

Comment: Why do people answer such low effort questions?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah my thoughts exactly. Who is worse, the person with the poor question, or the person who answers. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @TimBJames love it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-hidden-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Jquery validation.

```
$(".form").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true
        },
      },
    errorElement: 'div',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var placement = $(element).data('error');
        if (placement) {
            $(placement).append(error);
        }
        else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

Jquery validation:
https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
var $firstName = $(this).find( "[name='firstname']" );
if ( $firstName.val().length == 0 )
{
  alert("Please enter your First Name in the form");
  $firstName.focus();
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `this.firstname` could directly translate to `$('#firstname')` as we know it is an Id.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple . Details commented in Snippet

**SNIPPET**

```js
/* When any input has lost focus (ie blur)
|| and it's value is false, raise the alarm
*/
$('input').on('blur', function() {
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    alert('PUT SOMETHING IN THIS BOX');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input>
```