# Jquery to show and hide on button click and also move the button on the same click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner with Jquery, I've managed to get a button to show the div and the button to move to the right when the div is shown. I've seen similar questions for toggling visibility, etc but I also need to move the button on click but I have tried to follow their logic to get it to work with no success.

But when I do the opposite for when it's clicked again (hide the div and move the button back) I can't get it to work.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Html

```
<button id="myfilterFunction">Show/Hide</button>

    <div id="filterview">
    <?php echo $column_right; ?></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
        $( "#myfilterFunction" ).click(function() {                                 
            if ($( "#filterview" ).css('display', 'none')) {
            $('#filterview').show();
            $( "#myfilterFunction" ).css('margin-left', '300px');
            }

           if ($( "#filterview" ).css('display', 'block')) {
            $('#filterview').hide();
            $( "#myfilterFunction" ).css('margin-left', '0');
            }
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking the visibility of the element correctly. You should use `.is(":visible")` to check an element's visibility (using jQuery) and process the code accordingly:

```
$("#myfilterFunction").click(function () {
    // If the element is visible
    if ($("#filterview").is(":visible")) {
        // Code to process
        $('#filterview').hide();
        $("#myfilterFunction").css('margin-left', '0');
    } else {
        // If the element is not visible
        $('#filterview').show();
        $("#myfilterFunction").css('margin-left', '300px');
    }
});
```

`$("#filterview").css('display', 'none')` is used to actually SET the css display attribute of the element.

Comment: thanks a lot that fixed it and will help me for future!

Comment: Nice. And just for further reference, this SO question (and answers) is good for visibility checks like you're doing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-hidden-in-jquery)