# How to check if the element is visible using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using

`$('#analytics').toggle("slide");`

to toggle an item's visibility. But when I try to check if it's visible using

`$('#analytics').is(":visible")`

It always shows up as visible once it was toggled visible once...

What is the best way of checking the item's visibility if it's controlled using jQuery toggle function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-hidden-in-jquery)

Comment: depending on how you define your components, I would store it as a boolean in your object, and then apply and reference accordingly... As some nested structures can become quite complex.  The reason why i said is that maybe #analytics is visible, but some div children might not.

Comment: Best would be to come up with a live snippet/js fiddle that has that exact problem, so that everyone can see and test it

Comment: Re @Isac's point: You can do an [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: What you've shown in the question clearly does get `false` after the `slide` completes: https://jsfiddle.net/bwz2dkh5/ So we do need that MCVE.

Comment: could you please check my edit and feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `display` is what you are looking for:

**EDIT**

I just tried your own `$('#analytics').is(":visible")` and think there might be a problem with your *timing* (think asynchronous); try this code which waits until the animation ends before querying for visibility, at least in the snippet works, I would really appreciate your feedback.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $('#analytics').toggle("slide", function(){
    console.log($('#analytics').is(":visible") ? 'visible':'hidden');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="analytics">analytics</div>
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: Display is not the same as visibility, this will not work

Comment: @SterlingArcher, you did click *Run code snippet*, right?

Comment: What if the button is not visible on the screen (user scrolled down) while the css is still set to display?

Comment: @Scaramouche: There are several aspects to being visible, see [the jQuery documentation for the `:visible` feature the OP is using](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: @ChinLeung, I don't think *not visible because window has been scrolled* is something the OP was aiming for when he tried `$('#analytics').is(":visible")`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, the OP is using `$('#analytics').toggle("slide");` to toggle an element's visibility, and what `.toggle("slide")` does apart from animating it first is setting `display` to `none`, right? which is the key to my answer. of course you cannot narrow down visibility to the state of `display` but in this case, how the OP is toggling it, it is perfectly viable IMO

Comment: @Scaramouche: sure, but `:visible` checks that. So if `:visible` isn't working (according to the OP), doing your own check just on `display` isn't going to work either.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, please check my edit and tell me what you think

Comment: @Scaramouche: It's entirely *possible* (and why I posted a working example for the OP and asked the OP to show us the actual problem), but it's speculation until/unless they do so -- hence my posting a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Scaramouche answer was right and correct. The key was to check visibility inside the toggle function because of the async code execution. Thank you!