# remove parent if count of visible children is zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a function to remove parent if count of visible  children is `0`.

```html
<div>
    <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

```js
nores('postitle');

function nores(el) {
  el = $('.' + el);
  let pnt = el.parent();
  if ((el + ':visible').length == 0) {pnt.remove();}
}
```

Simply doesn't work and console is empty.

Comment: Any way to target the parent using some class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be to iterate over each different parent of `.postitle` elements. So that if you have more than one div with `.postitle` elements inside it would work.

**Here is an working example**

```js
$(".postitle").on('click', function() {
  $(this).hide();
  nores('postitle');
});

function nores(el) {
  var parents = $("." + el).parent();
  parents.each(function(i, e) {
    var parent = $(e);
    if (parent.children("." + el + ":visible").length <= 0) {
      parent.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.postitle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click on 'lorem ipsum' to hide it.
<br>
<div>
  One
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  Two
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  Three
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.is(':visible')` on the jquery element `el`

```js
nores('postitle');

function nores(el) {
  el = $('.' + el);
  let pnt = el.parent();
  console.log(el.is(':visible'))
  if ((el.is(':visible')) == false) {pnt.remove();}
}
```

```css
.postitle {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if there's more of such parents and .postitles on a page? You're not thinking on a `sliblings` base - which in my opinion is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You are selecting the parent element and then you try to concatenate that element with the string *':visible'* as if it were a string, which it is not. What you are probably trying to do is check if the parent element is visible. The answer to this related question explains how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/178450/1253156

For your example, this would mean:

```
nores('postitle');

function nores(el) {
  el = $('.' + el);
  let pnt = el.parent();
  if (el.is(':visible')) {pnt.remove();}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using `(el + ':visible').length` which is incorrect as `el` itself refers to the JQuery object due to this line of code `el = $('.' + el);` so what you need to do is keep the `el` of the parameter unchanged and then use this to check the length using `$(el + ':visible').length`:

```js
nores('postitle');

function nores(el) {
  let elem = $('.' + el);
  let pnt = elem.parent();
  if ($(el + ':visible').length == 0) {pnt.remove();}
}
```

```css
.postitle{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Some content
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle'>lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should think on a *Siblings* base.
Also why not passing the entire selector (not just a className)

Here's an example that accounts also for multiple wrappers/children relations

```js
nores('.postitle'); // Why not allow # . [] etc

function nores( selector ) {
  $(selector).each(function() {      
    if ( $(this).siblings().addBack().filter(function() {
      return $(this).is(":visible")
    }).length < 1 )  $(this).parent().remove();
  });
}
```

```css
.red { border: 2px solid red; }
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="red">
  <div class='postitle hidden'>1 lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle hidden'>2 lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle hidden'>3 lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<div class="red">
  <div class='postitle'>1 lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle hidden'>2 lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class='postitle'>3 lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```