# How to access visible html elements inside collapsed panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having two input elements of type text inside bootstrap panel. I am trying to get count of visible elements inside collapsed div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div id="inside"
            <label for="txt_1">Name</label>
            <input id="txt_1" type="text">
            <label for="txt_2" style="display:none;">Age</label>
            <input id="txt_2" type="text" style="display:none;">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

When i try to use below statement with panel expand i can get the length 1.

```
$('.panel input:visible').length
```

But the same line results 0 when panel is in collapsed state.
Is there any i can achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `:visible` selector to look for elements inside hidden parent? Not really clear what you need to accomplish

Comment: Hello vinoth, you are checking for `:visible`. As far as i understand this attribute, this will always be false, when the element is hidden, even when it is only hidden because the parent was set to `display: none;`

have a look at this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/178450/5086829

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".panel input").filter(function() { return $(this).css("display") == "none" })
```

This differentiates from a :hidden selector, since you're using inline display CSS rules

Edit: This won't do everything you're looking for, but should be the element filter you need in the existing code

Comment: Not accurate. css() as getter uses computed style not inline. Is not the same as checking `element.style.display`

Comment: Apologies if my explanation was inaccurate, I had tested it on JSFiddle and made an assumption after it behaved as expected. The code should perform in a desired manner, however

Comment: Will do the same as `:hidden` also

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script to get the all visible inputs length -

```
 $(".panel input:not([style*='display:none'])").length
```