# Perform Function when Element ID is Visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to perform a function after an element ID becomes visible on a page. I want to make it so that when an element with the ID **#discountbox** becomes visible, then peform this function.

**This is the javascript I've created so far:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(checkContainer);

function checkContainer () {
  if($('#discountbox').is(':visible'))){ //if the container is visible on the page
    $("#discountbox").clone().insertAfter(".discount-summary");
  } else {
    setTimeout(checkContainer, 50); //wait 50 ms, then try again
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an element is hidden in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178325/how-do-i-check-if-an-element-is-hidden-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd tried you code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltxye7w0/20/), and it works.

- what only i changed is just remove one ')'( maybe you alreay knew )

```
    if($('#discountbox').is(':visible')))
```

to

```
    if($('#discountbox').is(':visible'))
```